# Why does making a GET request to URL using fetch gives me an error while injecting a script tag programmatically with URL as src doesn't?

Tags: javascript, http, cors, fetch-api

If I inject a script programmatically like this:

```
((global, url) => {
    let s = document.createElement('script')
    s.src = url 
    global.document.body.appendChild(s)
})(window, 'https://example.com')
```

The request will go through just fine and the script will be inserted with the response to the request to "https://example.com" ... but if I try to make an explicit **fetch** request to the same URL I get a CORS error? Why is that happening?

Comment: Gets blocked for me

Comment: The url i put above is just an example for explanation purposes, just in case.

Comment: It does . Thanks for posting that link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just invented JSONP :D
Description from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp):

> JSONP stands for JSON with Padding. Requesting a file from another
> domain can cause problems, due to cross-domain policy. Requesting an
> external script from another domain does not have this problem. JSONP
> uses this advantage, and request files using the script tag instead of
> the XMLHttpRequest object.

Here is explanation on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-and-why-was-it-created)

Comment: Cool!. Didn't know I could do that.